# Using express session to share information across different routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, express-session

I am wondering if anyone could help me please. 
I have a react app that contains dialogflow (google's chatbot platform). I would like to share information in a user route to a dialogflow fulfillmentRoute using express-session. Here is my main server.js file. In the server.js I have declared an express-session

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors')

const users = require('./routes/api/users');


const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

require('./models/Users');



const app = express();
const session = require('express-session')

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());


require('./routes/fulfillmentRoutes')(app);


app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/users', users);


// Server static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

In the user.js route file, I then have this to save an email into a session variable;

**user.js**

```
router.post(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    sess = req.session;
    var emails = req.user.email;
    sess.emails; 

  res.json({ msg: 'Users Works' })

    res.json({
      id: req.user.id,
      firstname: req.user.firstname,
      lastname: req.user.lastname,
      email: req.user.email,
      week: req.user.week,
      age: req.user.age
    });
  }
);
```

In my dialogflow fullfillment route file, I have the following;

**fulfillmentRoutes.js**

```
const {WebhookClient, Payload, Card} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const express = require('express');

const chatbot = require('../chatbot/chatbot');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const sourceFile = require('./api/users.js');
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = app => {


    var router = express.Router();

  app.post('/api/df_text_query', async (req, res) => {

      let responses = await chatbot.textQuery(req.body.text, req.body.userID, req.body.parameters);
      res.send(responses[0].queryResult);



  });

  app.post('/api/df_event_query', async (req, res) => {
      let responses = await chatbot.eventQuery(req.body.event, req.body.userID, req.body.parameters);
      res.send(responses[0].queryResult);


  });


    app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

        const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

  async function welcome(agent) {


 let user = await User.findOne({'email': sess.emails});
             if (user !== null ) {

responseText = `${sess.emails}`;


      }

agent.add(responseText);

 } 

         let intentMap = new Map();
         intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
         agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });

return router;
}
```

In the welcome async function in fulfillment.js route, I use sess.emails that was declared in the user.js routes file. However the variable comes back undefined. Any guidance or help will be appreciated please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your user.js, `sess.emails;` is not being assigned any variable.

Can you try replacing it `sess.emails = emails;` and check if the emails field is undefined?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it is still undefined :-(

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionreloadcallback. Try to reload the session and log the whole session object. Maybe that will help

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However, where would I place this call back?

Comment: Try it in fulfillmentRoutes.js in the welcome function, at the beginning

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Not sure if it is something to do with the routes of fullfillmentRoutes.js? The correct routes being called into the server.js file?

Comment: I think I know the issue. You are creating a new router in fulfillmentRoles.js. Use the same router you created in server.js. Add `app.use('/api/roles', fulfillmentRoles);` where you only export the controller for fulfillmentRoles

Comment: So I would add this into the server.js file?

Comment: yes, there should be a single router handling your requests if you want to share data between them